# How to change the view in open/save dialog in Windows XP using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

I am tired of using the mouse to point and click just to change from the default view of small icon to details view in the open/save dialog in Windows XP, can I do it using keyboard shortcuts?

Another question I have: is there a similar way of sorting the files in the open/save dialog base on the last modified date in descending order?

Comment: AutoHotKey is always the answer.

Comment: There are a number of open/save dialogs in WindowsXP and they are dependent on the application you are running. Which program are you in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 7 and can't test the XP dialog box at the moment to give you the exact keystrokes, but you can hit tab and/or control-tab to highlight the correct set of toolbar button controls, then use the right/left arrows to highlight the view button, and spacebar to click it (possibly you need to control-downarrow or alt-downarrow to expand the list of selections.)  Sorry I can't be more exact, but those are the key combinations I use to navigate just about everywhere without a mouse.

I wouldn't exactly call it a "shortcut", but you can get there.

Comment: thanks, but I am looking for something like "ctrl-x" to do the trick.